# What does it mean to get a tree recursively from the GitHub API?

Tags: git, github, github-api

What's the difference between getting a tree normally and recursively from the GitHub API?
https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#get-a-tree-recursively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Normally* means getting the tree object with its attributes, no more.

*Recursively* means that any tree object (or subtree) referenced by the first tree will be expanded into its own objects, and so on with each depth level.